# vb.net cube root gives wrong value?

Tags: vb.net, math

I was simply looking for a way to get cube roots in vb.net. The consensus online is to use the formula:

```
<number> ^ (1 / 3)
```

I tried punching a few of these into the immediate window and here's what I get:

```
?1 ^ (1 / 3)
1.0
?8 ^ (1 / 3)
2.0
?27 ^ (1 / 3)
3.0
?64 ^ (1 / 3)
3.9999999999999996
```

Wait a minute.. Shouldn't the answer be 4.0? What happened? 4 * 4 * 4 = 64, not 3.9999999999999996 * 3.9999999999999996 * 3.9999999999999996 = 64. I'm usually good with math problems but I've spent too much time with this and I could use some help. I'm not as interested in finding out why this failed as much as I am interested in how to make this work given the number 64 and trying to get the cube root to equal 4.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Nice. Now how do I "fix" it? Rounding probably won't work because I also need to be able to detect when a number doesn't cube properly by checking the remainder. Ex: 65 ^ (1 / 3) = 4.0207257585890579

Comment: Not sure what you want to "fix", as there's nothing broken. :-) Searching here for `[.net] floating point comparisons` returns some useful links. You can't compare floating point values for exact equivalents except when they meet certain requirements, as the article I linked explains. You'll have to decide what an acceptable delta is, and make adjustments to allow rounding if the difference between the values falls within that delta limit or not and are considered equal. I don't know what your allowable delta would be to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Private Function CubedRoot(ByVal dNum As Double) As Double

        Return CType(CType(dNum ^ (1 / 3), Decimal), Double)

End Function
```